# Run a php function if a predefined page is visited

Tags: conditional-tags, cubepoints

I use the CubePoints plugin that rewards users with 1000 points via the following function:

```
if( function_exists(‘cp_alterPoints’) && is_user_logged_in() ){
    cp_alterPoints(cp_currentUser(), 1000);
}
```

Now, I would like to reward a user 1000 points for viewing one specific custom page that I created with with a page template.
Lets call it landingpage.php and the post ID of this page is 24122.

Is there any way to accomplish this?
Something like "if is page landingpage" (or "if is post=24122"), then perform the above function.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`is_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) conditional tag and at [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) in general.

`is_page()` takes both post IDs as well as slugs (and more) as arguments, hence you can choose how you'd like to identify the page in question.

With the above given ID, this, for instance, ought to work:

```
if( function_exists('cp_alterPoints') && is_page(24122) ){
    cp_alterPoints(cp_currentUser(), 1000);
}
```